# A back button/action for DIVs on one page website (hideStuff/showStuff function)

Tags: javascript, html, button, back

I'm a bit frustrated with finding a way to create a back button on one page website where content hides and appears in DIVs manipulated by hideStuff/showStuff function.

The search didn't solve my problem (maybe I missed something).

Thank you for suggestions and hints!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function showStuff(id) {
    document.getElementById(id).style.display='block';
  }

  function hideStuff(id) {
    document.getElementById(id).style.display='none';
  }
</script>

<div id = '1'>
  <a name="1"></a>
  <a href = '#2' onclick="showStuff('2'); hideStuff('1');">2</a><br>
  <a href = '#3' onclick="showStuff('3'); hideStuff('1');">3</a><br>
  <a href = '#4' onclick="showStuff('4'); hideStuff('1');">4</a>
  <br><br><i>('1')</i>
</div>

<div id = '2' style='display: none'>
  <a name="2"></a>
  <a href = '#1' onclick="showStuff('1'); hideStuff('2');">1</a><br>
  <a href = '#3' onclick="showStuff('3'); hideStuff('2');">3</a><br>
  <a href = '#4' onclick="showStuff('4'); hideStuff('2');">4</a>
  <br><br><i>('2')</i>
</div>

<div id = '3' style='display: none'>
  <a name="3"></a>
  <a href = '#1' onclick="showStuff('1'); hideStuff('3');">1</a><br>
  <a href = '#2' onclick="showStuff('2'); hideStuff('3');">2</a><br>
  <a href = '#4' onclick="showStuff('4'); hideStuff('3');">4</a>
  <br><br><i>('3')</i>
</div>

<div id = '4' style='display: none'>
  <a name="4"></a>
  <a href = '#1' onclick="showStuff('1'); hideStuff('4');">1</a><br>
  <a href = '#2' onclick="showStuff('2'); hideStuff('4');">2</a><br>
  <a href = '#3' onclick="showStuff('3'); hideStuff('4');">3</a>
  <br><br><i>('4')</i>
</div>

<a href="#" onclick="history.back(-1);">Back</a>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API#Adding_and_modifying_history_entries

Answer (score 0):

the history.back() will work on only url changes.what you are doing here is just showing and hiding the div's so history concept can't be used here

Comment: Thank you for the answer! But I know that it cannot work and that's the reason why ask here for some kind of solution. Or it's impossible at all in this case?

Comment: maintain an array that will store the ids that are hiding, so when you click the back ,loop through the array from backwards and show that particular div and hide rest of the divs

Answer (score 0):

You can use class instead of id for the elements and do some onclick fuction on the button for showing the element of related class and hiding the element of related class. Use toggle function. Hope it helps.